# Maximum graph edit distance between two graphs with the same degrees

Tags: graph-theory, markov-chains

Given a degree sequence $\mathbf{d} = (d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_n)$ with each $d_i \in \mathbb{N}$, how dissimilar can two graphs with the same degrees $\mathbf{d}$ be?
Specifically, if we use the graph edit distance (GED) as the metric, what is the maximum GED we can have?

**Definition:** The graph edit distance between two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ is defined as the minimum total number of operations of node insertions/deletions and edge insertions/deletions that can modify $G_1$ into a graph isomorphism of $G_2$

- Note: Since in the question we fix a degree sequence and thus the number of nodes, we can only consider edge insertions and deletions.

**Initial feeling:** The maximum value definitely depends on $\mathbf{d}$.

- The extremes cases such as empty graphs ($d_i \equiv 0$) and cliques ($d_i \equiv n - 1$) imply that the GED must be $0$.
- Intuitively, when each $d_i$ is far from $0$ and $n - 1$, we have more possibilities and we may expect higher maximum GED
- The set of graphs with a given $\mathbf{d}$ can be represented as a Markov Chain with "edge rewiring" operations

**Question:** Can we obtain closed-form formulae for the maximum GED, or at least bounds?

Comment: "Graph edit distance" seems to refer to a variety of metrics which all ask how we can turn one graph into another, but with different possible operations and costs. It would be helpful to know which one you're thinking of.

Comment: Thanks. I added some details! @MishaLavrov